# php drive letter to unc

Tags: php, html, unc

I have a web application that needs to pass the name and location of a file.  This file will be imported into a database using the database import tool, [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx).  The file sits on a network server in various folders.

My process consists of the following:

1. A HTML scripts that calls and displays a window file navigation
   window
2. The windows navigation window allow me to select the appropriate
   file
3. The HTML script calls a PHP script to format file and directory
   structure appropriately.

Currently the script returns the file name as:

`S:\filedir1\filedir2\filename.csv`

As a result of future process performed, I need to pass the UNC name as follows:

`\\serverS\serverfile1\serverfile2\filedir1\filedir2\filename.csv`

I tried to perform a `realpath` (PHP) function against the filename but it returns the same value that was passed in.

Is there a way to transform the drive specification to a UNC value?  Additionally, I cannot map network drives to the webserver.

TIA

Comment: Why don't you have the PHP script upload the file onto the database server?

Comment: I am a PHP novice and I do not want to break current functionality.  But if it the best solution I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shell_exec('net use')` and parse the output to retrieve the local->remote mapping then transform the file path string as needed.

---

Given `net use` on windows outputs something like:

```
New connections will not be remembered.

Status        Local        Remote        Network
------------------------------------------------------------------------
OK            S:           \\srv\data    Microsoft Windows-network

The command completed successfully.
```

---

#### Example:

```
$file = 'S:\filedir1\filedir2\filename.csv';

list($drive, $path) = explode(':', $file, 2);
$shellOutput = shell_exec('net use');

$matches = array();
$regex = '/\b'.$drive.':\s*([^\s]+)/';
preg_match($regex, $shellOutput, $matches);
$remote = $matches[1];

$unc = $remote.$path;

echo "$unc\n";
```

---

#### Output:

```
\\srv\data\filedir1\filedir2\filename.csv
```

---

Note this is just an example. Error checking and adjustments to the regular expression to account for the particulars of the environment are left as exercises to the reader.